# Why were there only 531 electoral votes in the US Presidential Election 2016?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college

I just read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_presidential_elections_by_Electoral_College_margin).

It says Trump won with a 304 to 227 for electoral votes.

That's 304 + 227 = 531 votes.

But the total number should be 538. Where did the 7 votes go?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is due to so-called *faithless electors*. Seven electors voted for a candidate other than the one they pledged to vote for. Three voted for Colin Powell, one for John Kasich, one for Ron Paul, one for Bernie Sanders, and one for Faith Spotted Eagle. The [FEC's report on the 2016 election](https://www.fec.gov/resources/cms-content/documents/federalelections2016.pdf) contains the map below showing which state these electors were from; Texas, Washington, and Hawaii.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faithless_electors_in_the_2016_United_States_presidential_election has some detailed information on how that played out. On top of the 7, another 3 electors (1 each from Maine, Minnesota, and Colorado, all Democrats) also attempted to vote against their pledge. The Maine elector was forced to change his vote to Clinton as pledged, the other two were replaced as electors entirely.

Comment: The terminology used is interesting: *faithless*.  Although I understand what they mean (and why), it's surely not a neutral word.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Given that they are (depending on State) expected or even required not to have a mind of their own, the terminology *voters* is just as interesting

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, it's a very odd system. I'm hoping to have some time to read more about it, in an attempt to understand all of its original (and possibly projected) purposes.  On the surface, the voters aren't really voting for what they think (a President and Vice President) and electors aren't really voting at all (they are more like couriers who, in most of the USA's states, only courier the message of the majority, and no one else).  And they wonder why so few people choose to vote.

Comment: @HagenVonEitzen it kinda begs the question why they even exist in states where they must vote a certain way.  Seems unconstitutional to me.  If the electors have no authority, are they even really electors?

Comment: In most states a faithless elector is either breaking the law and is subject to prosecution and penalties, or may be sued for breach of promise.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Sue for breach of promise?  Are you referring to civil court?  Does the plaintiff in such matters have to prove specific damages that resulted in a direct financial cost?  If so, what would they be?  Has anyone ever won such a case?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg The comments aren't intended for asking another question. They are good questions though. Suggest posting them as a new question.